# custom UITableViewCell, a UIView that holds two subviews, and scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has a method called updateCell. It adds a spotView which is just a UIView and self.spotView has a couple of subviews.

The issue is that when I scroll, the spotView will start off fine but when you scroll, it fills up with these subviews and inaccurate information. How do I fix this?

I have tried in prepareForReuse in my custom UITableViewCell and have tried to removeFromSuperview the subviews of spotview but that doesn't work either.

I have but am a bit confused what I need to get this working correctly. I see that I can set uilabel's to nil in prepare for reuse and that seems to work but these UIViews seem to hang out:

```
-(void)updateCell:(MenuItem *)item
{
    self.spotView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.spotView];


    [self renderHeader:menuItem.header];
    [self renderDetail:menuItem.detail];
    [self renderMeta:menuItem];
    ...
}

- (void)renderMeta:(MenuItem *)menuItem{
  if([self.spotView.subviews count]>0){
    NSLog(@"THERE ARE subviews in spotView in renderMeta for %@", menuItem.header);
  }else{
    NSLog(@"NO subviews in spotView in renderMeta for %@", menuItem.header);
  }


  for (UIView* view in [self.spotView subviews])
  {
    NSLog(@"!!!about to remove subviews here!!!");
        [view removeFromSuperview]; // <- not working
  }


  if([menuItem hasInstoreImage] || [menuItem hasTastingNotes]){
    if([menuItem hasInstoreImage]){
      UIView *instoreImageDot=[self circleWithColor:[UIColor redColor] radius:4];
      NSLog(@"adding instoreImageDot in renderMeta");
      [self.spotView addSubview:instoreImageDot];
    }else{
      NSLog(@"no instoreImageDot in renderMeta");
    }
```

### edit #1

Playing around with this, I found that trying to manipulate the views in the custom UITableViewCell was a big unpredictable. I was doing all of the custom UITableViewCell in code since I would be distributing as a Cocoapod internally to the company. What DID work was manipulating the cell in the ViewController specifically like:

```
// Does not work on iOS below 6.0
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if([cell isKindOfClass:[MenuItemCell class]]){
     NSLog(@"A MenuItem Class");
     MenuItemCell *miCell=(MenuItemCell *)cell;
     [miCell.spotView removeFromSuperview];
   }
}
```

## edit #2

Where / How updateCell is called (somewhat abbreviated as some code is taken out):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  [self.menuTV registerClass:[MenuItemCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MenuItemCell"]; 

  static NSString *MenuItemCellIdentifier=@"MenuItemCell";

  id dic=self.menu.listItems[indexPath.row];

  if([dic isKindOfClass:[EMBERSMenuItem class]]){
    //MenuItemCell *cell = [self.menuTV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MenuItemCellIdentifier];
    MenuItemCell *cell = [self.menuTV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MenuItemCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //MenuItem *menuItem=(MenuItem *)dic;
    MenuItem *menuItem=(MenuItem *)dic;

    cell.menuItem=menuItem; // <- probably shouldn't have this
    [cell updateCell:menuItem];

  }else{
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What comments do you see when you run this code? Does it hit the "remove subviews" one?

Comment: You also say that -updateCell: "adds a spotView," but that's not shown in the code. Does it really add a view, or does spotView already exist before calling the -updateCell: method?

Comment: can you upload an image of when the cell flips out?

Comment: When do you call updateCell method?

Comment: so I've edited the question to include where I add to contentView and have also found a semi-solution but it requires manipulating in the ViewController calling updateCell

Comment: I'm calling updateCell in the ViewController. Let me add that code. take a look at edit #1 though; not sure if this is how I shoudl be doing this but feel it's the most relialbe way for me to handle

Comment: @timpone you're adding unnecessary subviews every time you dequeue a cell. This is why you have repeated views inside your cell. Move your ``addSubview`` code into the ``init`` methods of your ``UITableViewCell`` subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your subviews in your cell in the cell's `init` methods. Otherwise, if you add subviews every time the cell gets rendered your cell will end having as many subviews as the rendering happens.

As an example:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self.contentView addSubview:mySubview];
    }
}
```

And then you can have a configuration method to inject your cell's data:

```
- (void)configureCellWithData:(id)data {
    self.mySubview.setText(data.text);
}
```

Comment: thx amb, hmm... let me retest that because I was originally doing that. Where  I started getting into trouble was when these subviews would get dynamically resized based upon the content. Should resetting the frame work doing it this way?

Comment: You can always implement ``layoutSubviews`` to calculate your cell content size.

Comment: thx amb - had to leave right when you left your other comment; let me update my code and see if this fixes it